# Python's Matplotlib: Override imshow extent

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, axes, imshow

I am plotting a georeferenced image with

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow( numpy.dstack((R,G,B)), extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax] )
```

Then I am plotting (on the same axes instance) a two arrays `x` and `y` which only covers a small extent of the figure:

```
ax.plot( x, y )
```

I want the size of my picture to match that of the line, but I cannot remove the `extent` kwarg from the RGB image, otherwise I would lose the coordinates matching.
What I tried to do is

```
ax.set_xlim( [x.min(), x.max()] )
```

but it is does not affect the figure. The axes limits I get is stull that of the `extent` keyword in the `imshow` method.

How do I set the axis limits without removing the `extent` named argument from the `imshow` call? I don't want to reproject my x and y coordinates.

Comment: You probably need to call `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` or update to mpl > 1.5.1.  Mutating objects does not trigger a re-draw (and this is a feature not a bug).

Comment: 1.5.1 is the latest stable version. `f.canvas.draw_idle()` does not work for me